# How to get a Unix.file_descr instance from an integer?

Tags: shell, unix, ocaml

I am writing a shell, and I can write the code to parse `exec 2<&0` easily with Menhir.

However, I cannot pass the parsed numbers to `Unix.dup2` to perform the file descriptor duplication.
`Unix.dup2` requires a `file_descriptor` instance, not an `int`.

Looking at the [Unix lib](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Unix.html), there isn't an obvious solution that allows me to get a file descriptor. The only thing that comes to mind is writing C bindings which I'd like to avoid if possible.

So is there some way to perform this transformation from `int` to `file_descr`? Some API in Menhir to grab a `file_descr` instead of an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports only the usual file built-in file descriptors, it's easy to translate just by enumeration:

```
let file_descr_of_int i =
    match i with
    | 0 -> Unix.stdin
    ! 1 -> Unix.stdout
    | 2 -> Unix.stderr
    | _ -> failwith "invalid file descriptor"
```

The actual Unix shells, of course, do in fact use whatever number you supply as the file descriptor. But using just 0, 1, 2 is good enough for the vast majority of work I've ever done with a shell.